# Excel: order effects in arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently using this expression to check if a cell contains at least one of a set of strings:

```
   A      B
1  abcd   =ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"a","x"},A1))
```

B1 will return true here. However if I change the order of the array as follows it returns false:

```
   A      B
1  abcd   =ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"x","a"},A1))
```

Why is that? Is there a better way to do this that's more elegant than using a bunch of OR()'s?

Comment: The items may need to be in alphabetic order.

Comment: I just tried setting A1 to "efg" and changed the formula to =ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"a","e","h"},A1)) and it still returns false

Comment: the way you use it, it needs to be in an OR... `=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"a","x"},A1)))` with Ctrl-Shift+Return is what you need here

Comment: Thanks @DirkReichel! This method works, but it doesn't scale very well. Ultimately, I'm looking to see if there exists a letter in A1 that is a member an arbitrary set of letters. Is there a better way to do this than =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...))?

Comment: while you could simply use `=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CHAR(ROW(97:122)),A1)))` to check for all lower case chars or use a range like `=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1:D3,A1)))` there is also the REGEX-way (but normal excel librarys do not contain that)... there is no real "easy" way to check for something like that... at least, there countless ways you can do it (just as a different approach: `=OR(LEN(A1)>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{"a","c","g"},"")))` will also work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, the answer to the original question "Why is that?" i.e. why does the result seem to be sensitive to the order of the strings in curly brackets is that the formula

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"a","x"},A1))
```

only looks at at the first string "a" because there is nothing to make it operate like an array formula and step through all the values "a","x" etc.

The usual procedure is to wrap the function in an aggregate function like SUM. If you do this you also have to add minus signs to make the TRUE/FALSE values from ISNUMBER behave as ones and zeroes and further wrap in SUMPRODUCT or enter it as an array formula to make it work:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"a","x"},A1))))
```

Even then it gives a numeric result which is not what you actually want.

@ Dirk Reichel's idea is therefore much better giving you:-

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"a","x"},A1)))
```

which works very nicely and incidentally doesn't need to be entered as an array formula.

Answer (score 2):

Say we have text in **A1** and we also have a list of sub-strings in column **C**.  These can be either single or multiple character substrings. We assign the **Name** - *KeyStrings* to the list of cells in column **C**

We want to know if any of the substrings is present in **A1**.

Enter the following in **B1**:

```
=NOT(LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,INDEX(KeyStrings,SUMPRODUCT(ROW(KeyStrings)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(KeyStrings,A1)))),"")))=LEN(A1))
```

The formula will report *True* if any of the substrings in column **C** can be found in **A1**

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(KeyStrings,A1)))` do the same in a simpler to understand way? Even COUNTIF would be a simpler approach to my eye... however, you have a working solution at least...

Answer (score 0):

I think since you have put a curly bracket there, it indicates an array search. (I am not an expert with arrays, so following is an educated guess).

What Excel is doing is in the first example, it is finding "a" in position no 1, so it is returning the no 1 to `ISNUMBER` function, which is `TRUE`. (Basically, compares "a" to a in abcd which is position 1, and doesn't find/look for[?] "x". Returns 1 for the "a", which is `TRUE` for `ISNUMBER` function)

In the 2nd code, "x" is compared to a from abcd,  which returns a non-numeric value (and doesn't find/look for[?] "a"), hence it is `FALSE`.

PS:

what I mean by Excel doesn't find/look for[?] the second or any element there on, seems to be based on how arrays and formulae are coded in. In the curly brackets, commas separate "columns" and semi-colons separate "rows". So you are entering a 2 column/1row array inside a search function. While there is nothing wrong with that, the `SEARCH` function itself may not be coded to look for any element in the array apart from the one in position [1,1]. Someone better informed with the inner workings of SEARCH function should confirm this answer. (If it is a completely wrong educated guess, I wouldn't mind taking it off)

Comment: I think you're on the right track here at least because at the end of the day SEARCH() is iterating through an ordered array and will return return #VALUE! as soon as it encounters a mismatch.